# Attaching DB after it has been detached

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using following code to attach my database to SQL Server. The problem is if I create a new file and attach it through my code but when I detach the file using SSMS and again run the same code, it gives error.

Error is:

> Unable to open the physical file "e:\dbForATTWithPWD.mdf". Operating
>   system error 2: "2(error not found)"

The code is:

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Server=MyHomeServer\SQLExpress;Database=master;Integrated Security=SSPI")
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("", conn)
cmd.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE MyHomeWithPWD ON ( FILENAME = 'e:\dbForATTWithPWD.mdf' ), ( FILENAME = 'e:\dbForATTWithPWD_log.ldf' ) FOR ATTACH"
conn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd.Dispose()
conn.Dispose()
```

Why is it happening.  All the permissions are the same even first time.

Also what should be the connection string if I need to use DB with uid `sa` and pwd `abc123` ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to making sure that nothing else is accessing that mdb file after you detach it.  I would probably shutdown that SQLServer instance and restart.  Also, I'd make sure that you could detach and reattach in SSMS.

For your connection string try this: "Server=YOURSVR;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection=False;User ID=sa;Password=abc123;"

Comment: Thanks ! I tried to attach  it through SSMS, it works but through my code, it says unable to open physical file.  Newly created has no problem.